# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on CIContext Draw Image

Tags: ios, swift, core-image

I'm having this weird crash that only happens sometimes:

[image: crash log]

It's happening on the "drawImage" call.

```
self.glkv?.bindDrawable()
self.ciContext?.drawImage(self.currentImage!, inRect: inrect, fromRect: self.currentImage!.extent())
self.glkv?.display()
```

Comment: Did you ever work this one out? I'm getting the exact same thing and can't for the life of me solve it :(

Answer (score 1):

EXC_BAD_ACCESS often happens when a pointer to a memory address is dereferenced unexpectedly, maybe meaning an object is nil when it shouldn't be; however, the compiler may not catch that if the property is allowed to be nil, as in the case of the `ciContext` and `drawImage` line. I would check those values in the debugger to make sure a value isn't nil when it's not supposed to be. You can do that using a breakpoint.

Comment: Yes, but the error is happening on system's OpenGL code, how can I know what is being dereferenced?

Comment: `ciContext` may not be retained, which it needs to be to run that method. Maybe try changing the `?` to a `!` and see if it crashes differently? Or making the optional property unwrapped by initializing it on declaration.

Comment: But if ciContext was nil, this line wouldn't even be called..  Also, this error happens so rarely that I don't know yet how to reproduce it